# What is the purpose of std::thread constructor third template parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, templates

This is how `std::thread` constructor declared (using Visual Studio 2015):

```
template<class _Fn,
class... _Args,
class = typename enable_if<
    !is_same<typename decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value>::type>
explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
```

No questions regarding `_Fn` and `_Args`, however, that third `class = ...` confuses me totally. What does it do, how does it work and what is it for?

Comment: Apparently, it's disabling this constructor in case `_Fn` is of type `std::thread`; I suspect it's to avoid ambiguous call errors with the copy constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is an example of conditionally enabling the overload using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

This overload shouldn't be considered for overload resolution if the first argument is of type `std::thread`.

Note that the raw source of C++ standard headers **is not intended to be read**.  It is also **not intended to be mimiced**.  C++ compiler implementors can do many things in their std header implementations that you cannot and should not do outside of those headers.  The least of which is starting a variable with an `_` followed by an upper case letter (which is banned in user code).

Examine the type of the default argument if `_Fn` is a `std::thread`, a reference to same, or reference to a cv modified same.

```
typename enable_if<
!is_same<typename decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value>::type>
```

`decay<_Fn>::type` strips references and cv qualifications.  It also converts references-to-functions to pointers-to-function and references-to-arrays to pointers-to-first-element, but that isn't important here.

Suppose `_Fn` was `thread&`.  I will evalulate:

```
typename enable_if<
!is_same<typename decay<thread&>::type, thread>::value>::type>
typename enable_if<
!is_same<thread, thread>::value>::type>
typename enable_if<
!true>::type>
typename enable_if<
false>::type>
/* substitution failure occurs */>
```

`enable_if<B>::type` only exists if `B` is `true`; when `_Fn` is a thread, it is false, thus there is a substitution failure during overload resolution.

SFINAE means substitution failure is not an error, and instead of the compiler complaining, it simply removes this overload from consideration.  And the `thread(thread const&)` (which I believe is `=delete`ed) constructor is found instead.

Answer (score 5):

The 3rd unnamed template parameter has a default value, which is used to satisfy the following requirement of the [constructor of std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) via [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), to avoid the disturbance when the move constructor is intended to be invoked.

> This constructor does not participate in overload resolution if [`std::decay_t<Function>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is the same type as [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).